# Write Selenium Test to select a tab in Kendo Tabstrip using Text

Tags: selenium, kendo-ui

I am trying to write Selenium Test to select a tab from Kendo UI's Tabstrip using the Text of the tab. 
I tried to find the information but I could not find anything. Thanks for your help!

```
<div id="tabstrip">
    <img src="/Styles/kendoui/BlueOpal/loading_2x.gif" class="ajax-loader">
    <ul>
        <li class="panel-header">Tab1</li>
        <li class="panel-header">Tab2</li>
        <li class="panel-header">Tab3</li>
    </ul>
........
```

Comment: You want to read this https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this locator

```
WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tabstrip']/ul/li[contains(text(),'Tab1')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean clicking on Tab (when you meant selecting a tab)
try with this xpath:  //div[@id='tabstrip']//*[contains(text(),'Tab1')]